# JQuery scrollTop doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am trying to scroll to a div with two classes `class="media unread"`

I've place this line inside `application.js` inside `$(document).ready(function() {`

```
$("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: $(".media.unread").offset().top - (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) + $(".media.unread").height() + 15} , 800);
```

This works well in firefox, but on chrome I need to manually scroll a bit more down for it to reach the div and make it visible

Am I missing something? Or my chrome is broken?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `$('.media.unread').offset().top` for scrollTop?
I think, you can get it.

If I have a mistake, please tell me details!!

Thx